# Redux: array of combined reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The structure of my combined reducers is:

> - elements
> - selectedElement

The element's structure is:

```
{
   "1": {
       id: "1",
       type: ...
       ...
     },
   "2": {
       id: "2",
       type: ...
   }
}
```

The selected element structure is:

```
 {
     id: "2"
 }
```

Actions with types such as "ADD_ELEMENT" are handled by the element reducer and actions with types such as "SET_SELECTED" are handled by the selectedElement reducer.

Now I want to add another level, Screen:

> - screen
>
>   - elements
>   - selectedElement
> - screen
>
>   - elements
>   - selectedElement

So I have an array of my previous structure. How can I make this happen? How do you build an array of combined reducer that knows to which of them to pass actions such as "ADD_ELEMENT"? I realise I can add a screenId to each element (and action) but I would like to separate the elements of each screen.

Comment: Why not use different action types like "ADD_SCREEN" or "SET_SCREEN"? Types should signify what your app is doing, not be shared. In your reducer, multiple types can share the same functionality.

Comment: Do you mean for the screen reducer - of course. My question is how do I handle many elements separated to screens? My state needs to change from one object to an array of object.

Comment: State should be immutable. So you if you need an array, use an array. I'm not sure what you mean by "how do I handle many elements separated to screens?"

Comment: I want to avoid changing my reducers. If I use an array for my state it means I need to change all my reducers and pass a screenId in my actions, doesn't it?

Comment: something like that http://www.webpackbin.com/N1SFG90D- ?

Comment: @Utro receiving "Module not found: Error:" on the link

Comment: try http://www.webpackbin.com/41IdyoAwZ

Comment: Same error:
http://files.parsetfss.com/c80e11bf-75e2-4fde-a341-518af5c53eb8/tfss-2134fa52-8cec-4c87-b416-9353b4eea3d9-Screen%20Shot%202016-07-25%20at%209.25.15%20AM.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118180/discussion-between-utro-and-guy).